# Microsoft Graph API - Get profile picture with defined size

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I already used a beta version of the unified API to get the profile picture of the user with size of 48x48.
Now I'm using the Microsoft Graph API and tried to get the profile picture with this size too. But I only get the 648x648 one...
Is there a way to get the picture in 48x48?

this is my request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com/photo
```

Here the Documentation: 
http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

AJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like now you can do:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos('{size}')/$value`

Example:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos('48x48')/$value`

The available sizes are `'48x48'`, `'64x64'`, `'96x96'`, `'120x120'`, `'240x240'`, `'360x360'`,`'432x432'`, `'504x504'`, and `'648x648'`.

I gleaned that from the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/photo-rest-operations) that Reken Liu gave in the previous answer

Comment: It can also be written as: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/$value` And a more recent link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: This is for retrieving your own (logged in user's) profile picture. However, if you want to grab another user's profile picture, as one would do via the request URL shown in the question, how would it work then?

Comment: Looks like: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photos('48x48')/$value`.  BTW: [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) is a great resource for trying these out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds only the beta version API supports getting photo by size now. The default API end with /photo will get the largest available photo. Here's another reference for User Photo REST API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/photo-rest-operations
If you choose the API Version in the above article, you will see the differences.

Comment: 1.5 years later and this is still an issue. that's ridiculous.