# Microsoft Graph API x C# - Get profile picture with defined size

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to retrieve all users in my Azure Active Directory with their profile photo.

My request looks like this:

`var photo = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync()`

I know that it is theoretically possible to define the desired size: [Microsoft Graph API - Get profile picture with defined size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880810/microsoft-graph-api-get-profile-picture-with-defined-size)

Now I'm wondering how to do that in C#. I know that it actually works like this for groups:

`var photo = await _graphServiceClient.Groups[groupId].Photos["64x64"].Content.Request().GetAsync()`

If I'm using the brackets in my user request, it says "Cannot apply indexing...".

`var photo = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Photo["64x64"].Content.Request().GetAsync()`

I hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need `Photos` not `Photo`

```
var photo = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Photos["64x64"].Content.Request().GetAsync()
```